# Remove price filter for specific category

Tags: magento2, layout, filter

I can remove all filters in category with this line:

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

But, I need to remove only price filter for specific category. Can I do this with "Layout Update XML"?

This is a filter block structure:

[image]

I can use JS to find and remove price filter title or use css to remove last two elements for `filter-options`. But maybe there is another way to remove it completely via XML?

Thanks?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add a custom class on the `body` tag for that category via layout update XML, and then hide the price filter when that class exists:

First, depending on your theme and if you have a custom layered navigation module installed, you need to add a CSS class name to identify the price filter. If you're using standard Magento layered navigation, you need to add the filter view file inside your theme (copy from parent theme): `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml`

And around line 38, add the filter code in class attribute:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
        [...]
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item filter-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $filter->getCode() ?>">
            [...]
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then, add category layout update xml:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="hide-price-filter"/>
</body>
```

And finally a CSS rule:

```
body.hide-price-filter {
    .filter-price {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Of course, there are other methods too, which can completely remove the filter from the category, if proposed solution is not acceptable, but you would have to extend the `Magento_LayeredNavigation` module via plugins and add the desired functionality

Comment: Hi. Thank's for the reply. I already have a class on the `body` tag. And I can remove `price-slider-wrap`. But, what about `filter-options-title` and `filter-options-content`? Watch the screen in my question. I can use JS, to find a price filter title and remove it or use css, for hiding the last elements. But, maybe there someone know a better way to remove it completely via xml?

Comment: You can't via XML without making a module. Based on your updated answer, you can add the filter specific class to both `dt` and `dd` tags